# Inserting function into file that extends component in React

Tags: reactjs, function, button, setstate, use-state

I'm trying to create a `useState` to handle clicks for a dropdown button in React; but I can't use a function under a class that extends component, so I've been working on changing it as a constructor. I've tried multiple different ways but this was the original:

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {

function Navbar() { 
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () =>(!click);
}
    
  render() {
    return (
        <nav className='dropdown'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>
                test button
          </Link>
           <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
           </div>
        </nav>
    );
  
 }
```

Comment: What happens in your app and what do you want it to do differently? Have you done any debugging? Do you have the React Dev Tools installed in your browser? If not, be sure to do that and learn how to use them. They are a very useful tool in tracking down bugs like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use functional components in order to use react hooks. Then use `setClick` function to set the updated state as follows.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Navbar() {
 
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => setClick(value => !value);

    return (
        <nav className='dropdown'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>
                test button
          </Link>
           <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
           </div>
        </nav>
    );
  
  }
```

Comment: thank you! i thought if i took out extend component all of the other classNames i have in this wouldnt work! Also didnt try taking out the render still new to react.

Comment: You can use both class and functional component in react. Please check how to use state management in both ways.

Comment: If this solve your issue, please kindly accept it as the answer and upvote.